# /sbin/init is shared object?

Tags: linux, init

I know 'init' is first process that is started after the kernel is loaded, but there is an ambiguity for me. If it is a process it must have a binary executable file. However, the following shared object is compiled code that looks like an executable file, but there is no main function.

```
sardari@mint / $ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=7a4c688d009fc1f06ffc692f5f42ab09e68582b2, stripped
```

Apparently a shared object can be an executable file, but why?

Comment: If you are looking for a `main` symbol using `nm`, you won't see it in a stripped binary. Use `readelf -a` to determine the entry point (which usually points to the [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) anyway). Since `init` is dynamic, strictly speaking it is the dynamic linker (in the `.interp` section, e.g. `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) that executes first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a file compiled with `-pie` (**Position Independent Executable**) such as :

```
gcc -pie -fPIC hello.c
```

Then you have :

```
#file ./a.out 
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x2afb7892000a1dc5b9010c591b75987188aa2d66, stripped
```

If you need more information , You can visit [Position-independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)

Comment: @soroosh ,  It's related to **Page Independent Code** http://lfs.osuosl.org/hlfs/view/unstable/glibc/chapter02/pie.html

Comment: Position Independent Executable is what I'm looking for. When a code using all PIC libraries, it could compiled as PIE. I cant find answer for "WHY" part of question!